# Unrecognized selector when using sbjson

Tags: ios, json, sbjson

i'm trying to follow this tutorial here http://ios-blog.co.uk/iphone-development-tutorials/parsing-json-on-ios-with-asihttprequest-and-sbjson/ to do both the ASIHttp and SBJSon tutorial at the same time and all is well until the line

```
NSMutableArray *colorTitles = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"title"];
```

where it would crash with the error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9340d20'
```

i've tried using NSArray, NSString and am running out of ideas... my codes are exavtly the same with the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Probably happens when you try Call the method which don't belong corresponding Class or it superClass then in this case you get error:`unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

So Check what JSON you getting.
According to the JSON Response(data)try to parse it.

I'd like to tell you about the JSON:

`JSON is built on two structures:`

```
A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.
```

In JSON, they take on these forms:

**Object**

An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by , (comma).

**Array:**

An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [ (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket). Values are separated by , (comma).

**Value**

A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.

I think you are getting the Value JSON, so Try below. and one thing you can not assign(create object) the value to NSmutableArray Literally. so Please do in below Manner.

```
NSArray *colorTitles = [jsonDictionary valueForKey:@"title"];
```

If you still don't get the Proper result.

http://www.json.org/

Comment: uh sorry the format ran off, but its something like that, and yea i changed it to nsarray but still the same result with the error

Comment: sorry pasted an irrelevant json but the json is as http://www.colourlovers.com/api/colors?format=json as im doing the tutorial

Comment: and i think the json structure is of an array of objects?

Comment: here you get the Array of values and your values are objects, please let me check more.wait for a while...!!

Comment: Use NAArray instead of NSMUtableArray As:
NSArray *colorTitles = [jsonDictionary valueForKey:@"title"];

Comment: if ([jsonDictionary isMemberOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
  NSLog(@"if here");
  NSArray *t = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"title ];
 }else {
  NSLog(@"else here");
  NSDictionary *ids = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"title"];
 }

Comment: @eddy use this i think you getting the the JSON response as Values NSArray *colorTitles =[jsonDictionary valueForKey:@"title"];.

Comment: kamar! ure a lifesaver! thanx that did the trick, its valueForKey LOL thanx!

Answer (score 0):

`objectForKey` is a method of `NSDictionary`, not `NSArray`. You are probably missing (or overdoing) a step in the JSON string parsing.

Comment: i've followed exactly the steps on that website, could it be the type that i'm allocating the objectForKey is wrong? if yes, what should be the right type?

Comment: @eddy please see you are assinging the some Value to NSMutableArray litrally , which is not right ,in this point crash mayoccur.and second thing you need to check your JSON response(what you get values, array, object).in your code you calling [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"title"];.it may be possible you are getting values instead of Object. SO check your Response

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this kind of error comes when you are trying to access a dealloc'd object. Check if you are over-releasing or not retaining the `jsonDictionary`.

Comment: am i right to do by retaining the `jsonDictionary, it would mean i need to declare it in the .h file with the @property(retain) like that? or am i getting the wrong idea :(

Comment: No need to go to .h file. Only check that you are not releasing the object before this line. If you have declared the variable in the same method, this should work. Could you paste your code for this method?

Comment: @Sailesh this is not true this eror comes when your are trying access the method which is not exist in the Corresponding class(or it's subclass).

Comment: Yes, but why is that happening in this case, when the object is declared as NSMutableDictionary? This is because the object is dealloc'd, and at run time, that memory address represent some random data, which is falsely read as a `__NSArrayM` object. Note that this is not even `NSArray` but some internal class. Hence, one plausible explanation is that whatever resided on that mem location is now released and not accessible.

Comment: I only declared the NSMutable/NSArray in the method and nope its not released as far as i can see...

Comment: the method is 
`-(void) requestFinished: (ASIHTTPRequest *) request {
 NSString *theJSON = [request responseString];
 
 SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
 
 
 // Actually parsing the JSON
 NSMutableDictionary *jsonDictionary = [parser objectWithString:theJSON error:nil];
 NSLog(@"the json %@", jsonDictionary);
 
 
 
 NSString *key = @"itemname"; 
 NSArray *t = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:key ];

}`

Comment: `[parser objectWithString:.. ]` must be returning an array and not a dictionary. Put a check like: `if ([parsedObject isMemberOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) { //do stuff }